# CORS not working when page is compressed/cached

Tags: wordpress, caching, cors, w3-total-cache

At the moment I have 2 sites: A - with content and CORS header enabled, B - in which I want to embed content using AJAX Include Script.

Everything works great when page is not compressed. When W3 Total Cache is enabled, I get XMLHttpRequest Exception 101.

**Weird behavior:** 
When I navigate to page where content should be and then purge A site's page cache and refresh B site, everything loads up fine. When I clear browser cache and refresh - XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 again. It's the same for Chrome, Firefox and Safari(both, desktop and mobile).

What's going wrong when compression is enabled?

p.s. I've tried setting up CORS by PHP and Apache. Makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that when you turn compression on, the response has the `Content-Encoding` header in it? This header would need to be added to the CORS `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header.

Comment: I have no Content-Encoding in my header response and adding it didn't help. However I solved the problem, looks like my public hosting is not compatible with W3 Disk:Enhanced method.